# How to Install Python Packages for Specific Python Version?

Tags: python, package, version

I have a problem with Python package downloads. I have Python 3.10 installed on my computer. At the same time, **python 3.8** is installed at conda environment.

[Valid Kernels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uudz.png)

I can't install packages with pip for **Python 3.10** version on command prompt. The package is always installed for the conda enviroment. Also, typing `python --version` on the command prompt shows version is 3.8. My question is how can I install python package for python 3.10 installed on my computer.

[Python Version on command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcgCp.png)

Comment: `conda deactivate` to switch to your system python.

Comment: In general, you should use `<python_interpreter> -m pip install <package>` to install a package for a specific installation of python on your system. Obviously, this requires you be able to invoke the correct version of python itself, which requires keeping installations and virtual installations apart.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this line in the cmd when installing a package and it should work:

```
python3.1 -m pip install yourpackagename
```